Email Link (Link to Item) in Power Automate Flow opens form, but doesn't display Radio buttons?
I have a strange scenario which I can't figure out.  So I have a Power Automate flow that sends an email with a Link to Item in the body.  When you click on it, it successfully launches the PowerApps form in SharePoint with all the fields populated, etc.  EXCEPT, it won't display my Radio buttons for one of the fields.  But if I go to the list, double-click the item, those buttons are visible.  The Datacard and Datacardkey are visible, just not the buttons.  There are no Visible properties on the Radio control or the Datacard itself.  So here's what happens when you click on the Email link: 
And here's what you see if you go to the list and double click the item:

I have no clue why these would be different.  The "Renew this Contractor Access Request" field's Visible property is "True", as is the Radio control.
Does anyone know why those radio buttons won't display when you launch the form from the email link?
Thank you!

What is the DisplayMode property of radio control? Does the link from email open display/view form or edit form?
